# How to make and sort array of tuples in R

Tags: arrays, r, sorting, tuples

I have couple of tuples and I need to sort them according to the second item.
Here is a pseudocode:

```
events <- vector(mode = "list", length = 5)
events[[1]] <- c(3,1.4)
events[[2]] <- c(2,1.8)
events[[3]] <- c(8,5.3)
events[[4]] <- c(6,1.4)
events[[5]] <- c(6,5.4)

#sort according to second item in tuple
sort(events)
events
```

I would like to get a result that would be like this:

```
[c(3,1.4),c(6,1.4),c(2,1.8),c(8,5.3),c(6,5.4)]
```

Comment: [This link](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/r-sorting-a-data-frame-by-the-contents-of-a-column/) illustrates a useful way to do this with data frames. It might be overkill for your particular problem at hand, but it's worth knowing for the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to extract the second elements of each component of the list using `[` and then order them and use that ordering to sort `events`.

First, create the data object you appear to have:

```
events <- vector(mode = "list", length = 5)
events[[1]] <- c(3,1.4)
events[[2]] <- c(2,1.8)
events[[3]] <- c(8,5.3)
events[[4]] <- c(6,1.4)
events[[5]] <- c(6,5.4)
```

The next step is to extract the second elements of each of the list components. We can do that using `sapply()` to apply the `[` function. The `2` below refers to the second element.

```
> sapply(events, `[`, 2)
[1] 1.4 1.8 5.3 1.4 5.4
```

We can then get the ordering of these second elements using `order()`

```
> ord <- order(sapply(events, `[`, 2))
> ord
[1] 1 4 2 3 5
```

Which we can then use to order the list of `events`

```
> events[ord]
[[1]]
[1] 3.0 1.4

[[2]]
[1] 6.0 1.4

[[3]]
[1] 2.0 1.8

[[4]]
[1] 8.0 5.3

[[5]]
[1] 6.0 5.4
```

Comment: Well, I "wasted my time replying" because I was surprised that it would be, as I consider it, tedious. "Horrendous" might've been overstating it. I'm not insulting the language or you for your practice of it, actually, after having looked at it more, I think it's kind of fun because it's an approach I hadn't yet encountered. But I did wrap your logic in something that resembles python's approach so that it would be easier to use (with the exception of calling the parameter reverse, that was just for conventio). https://github.com/JadeSpy/Snippets-for-R/blob/main/sortingWrapperForMultipleDims.r